# Glusterfs how to balance bricks in single server?

Tags: glusterfs

My env: CentOS 7, GlusterFS 8

At first, I add 2 bricks to created a distribute volume.Later, I add a brcik to extended this  volume.All operations were in single server.

At now, the usage of 3 bricks are 81% 83% 55%, I have tried `gluster volume rebalance test-volume start`,it was worked,but the bricks still not balance. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should do type this command:

```
gluster volume rebalance test-volume fix-layout start
```

this will work now